# Receiving: 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] Cannot set headers warning', but data is posting to table?

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, controller, http-headers

I have an app.post that is receiving this error message:

**Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client**

...but data is publishing to the MySQL Table.

What is happening? Where is it happeneing? How can I resolve this issue?

```
 app.post("/api/tracking/retrieve", (req, res) => {

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let carrierTrackers = [
        {
            carrier: 'USPS',
            trackingCode: '940019999999'
        },
        {
            carrier: 'UPS',
            trackingCode: '94001888888'
        }
    ];

    carrierTrackers.forEach((carrierTracker) => {
        const tracker = new api.Tracker({
            tracking_code: carrierTracker.trackingCode,
            carrier: carrierTracker.carrier
        })

        tracker
            .save()
            .then(
                console.log(carrierTracker.carrier, carrierTracker.trackingCode),
        )
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('There has been an error with your submission.')
            });

        table = 'tracking_table';
        col = ['user_id', 'tracking_number'];
        val = [user_id, tracker.tracking_code];

        main.create(table, col, val, function (data) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({
                id: "",
                user_id: user_id,
                tracking_number: data.tracking_code
            })); 
        })
        res.end()
    })
});
```

Comment: you're sending response inside a `forEach` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved the issue:

```
app.post("/api/tracking/retrieve", (req, res) => {

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    // An array of objects //
    let carrierTrackers = [
        {
            carrier: 'USPS',
            trackingCode: '940019999999'
        },
        {
            carrier: 'UPS',
            trackingCode: '94001888888'
        }
    ];

    carrierTrackers.forEach((carrierTracker) => {
        const tracker = new api.Tracker({
            tracking_code: carrierTracker.trackingCode,
            carrier: carrierTracker.carrier
        })

        table = 'tracking_table';
        col = ['user_id', 'tracking_number'];
        val = [user_id, tracker.tracking_code];

        main.create(table, col, val, function (data) {
        })

    })
    res.end()
});
```